# Retrieve final (incomplete) batch of custom Data Generator

Tags: tensorflow, keras, batch-processing, data-generation

I have a made a custom data generator that outputs batches of image sequences of shape (batch size, sequence length, image height, image width, channels), along with two labels y1 and y2.

However, I cant seem to retrieve the final (incomplete) batch during training. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, training_set=False, batch_size=32, dim=(224, 224), n_channels=3, shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.training_set = training_set
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        num_batchs_per_epoch = int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))
        return num_batchs_per_epoch

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        start = index*self.batch_size
        end = (index+1)*self.batch_size
        indexes = self.indexes[start:end]
        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]
        # Generate data
        X, y1, y2 = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)
        return X, [y1, y2]

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, 3, *dim, n_channels)
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, 3, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y1 = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=float)
        y2 = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            sequence = [s for s in ID]
            f0, f1, f2 = [self.load_resize_image(image) for image in sequence]

            # preprocess steps 
            f0 = self.preprocess(f0, self.training_set)
            f1 = self.preprocess(f1, self.training_set)
            f2 = self.preprocess(f2, self.training_set)

            triplet = np.concatenate((f0,f1,f2), axis=0)
            X[i,:,:,:,:] = triplet

            ID = tuple(ID)
            y1[i] = self.labels[ID][0]
            y2[i] = self.labels[ID][1]

        return X, y1, y2 

    def preprocess(self, img, training_set):

      if self.training_set:
        # apply transformations
        gen = ImageDataGenerator()
        img[0,:,:,:] = gen.apply_transform(x=img[0,:,:,:], transform_parameters={'theta':random.uniform(-180, 180),
                                                              'brightness': random.uniform(0.8, 1.2), 
                                                              'flip_horizontal': random.getrandbits(1),
                                                              'shear': random.uniform(0,5),
                                                              'zx': random.uniform(0.9,1.1),
                                                              'zy': random.uniform(0.9,1.1),
                                                              'flip_vertical': random.getrandbits(1)
                                                              })

      return img

    def load_resize_image(self, image):

        img = cv2.imread(image)
        img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img_array = np.array(img)
        img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
        return img_array
```

And at training...

```
history = model.fit(
    training_generator,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code will always omit the last batch of data, due to this line of code:

```
int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))
```

See the example below:

```
number_of_samples = 1002
batch_size = 4
num_batches_per_epoch = int(np.floor(number_of_samples  / 4))

num_batches_per_epoch (=250, if number_of_samples == 1000,1001,1002,1003)
```

The way the dataset is written, it will always omit one batch, which is not a problem, since in essence it is incomplete.

As you are shuffling at the end of each epoch:

```
if self.shuffle == True:
   np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)
```

the not seen few samples in an epoch will definitely be seen in later epochs.

Comment: thanks for your response, your explanation makes a lot of sense. my question now is.. how do i retrieve the final partial batch? i tried to add 1 to `int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))` but that simply added another complete batch

Comment: You cannot tackle that if you expect to train on that batch. A tricky solution would be to add previously seen data from the dataset again in the last batch provided the number of samples is not divisible by the batch_size. Again, I wouldn't bother that much, your training will not suffer from not seeing those 2/3 elements in one epoch, as you shuffle it will "see" them in later epochs.

Comment: The easiest way to do this (the previous comment) would be to re-add samples from your dataset in order to ensure the number of samples is divisible with batch_size, and only then train again. However that is not necessary, as you network will not be affected by that.

Comment: By the way if my answer helped you could you please accept it? Thank you.